# XCode 4.5 Storyboard does not show some of navigation bars of my view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, storyboard

Ater updating XCode to 4.5,  some of navigation bars of my view controllers are gone and it shows the view controller smaller than the normal size. here is the picture of my storyboard:
[image]

As you can see, they are smaller than the normal size, even the size of iPhone 4. I have some bar button items on the navigation bar that I want to work on them, it shows the bar button when I run the application on simulator or on device but it doesn't show in the storyboard. Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug for Xcode 4.5
In order to fix this problem I copied and pasted the view controllers and It showed the navigation bar, then I deleted the old view controllers and connected the new controller to the rest of the view controllers. Although I fixed this issue but I know that this is not the efficient way to fix this problem, if anybody has any idea to fix it by a better method, I would appreciated.

Comment: It's more easy to delete only Navigation Controller and embed Table View in a new Navigation Controller. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (sort of) solution for my case of navigation bars disappearing from the storyboard when using Xcode 4.6. Yes, it does appear to be a bug in Xcode. However, when I clicked on various segues in the storyboard linking the navigation controllers together I found that the storyboard navigation bars would sometimes appear (and sometimes disappear).

Again, I'm pretty sure it's a bug and that for some reason Xcode is sometimes getting confused about whether or not it should display a storyboard navigation bar when a segue in the storyboard is clicked. Just try clicking away on the various segues until you find that the navigation bars all appear - or at least the one you're currently working on appears.

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same for me but after hours I've discovered the problem was simple: Please make sure that your segue is set for Push otherwise the navigation bar won't appear!